# Trying to Make a Building

Tags: java

Where should I use print and println statements to draw a building on my console window. Let's say the height of the building will be 2 then it should show two storeyed building like the one below.

OUTPUT

[image]

Well, it looks to me like it's nested loops. I think the most outer loop should be the number of stories. In that loop have another loop for the number of windows, and in that another one for how tall it is, then inside, how wide.
Could anyone please give me an example how to do it? I know I have to use for loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BuildingAssign {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        int input;  
        int stories;
        int windows;
        int wide;
        int tall;
        final int MAXSTORIESHIGH= 4;
        final int MINSTORIESHIGH = 1;
        final int MAXWINDOWS = 16;
        final int MINWINDOWS = 2;
        final int MAXWIDE = 4;
        final int MINWINDE = 3;
        final int MAXTALL = 4;
        final int MINTALL =3 ;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("How many stories high the building will be? (1-4): ");
            stories = in.nextInt();
        }while (stories < MINSTORIESHIGH || stories > MAXSTORIESHIGH);

        do {
            System.out.print("How many windows on each story? (2-16): ");
            windows = in.nextInt();
        }while (windows < MINWINDOWS || windows > MAXWINDOWS);

        if (stories < 2){
            System.out.print("It won't work");

        }

        do {
            System.out.print("How wide each window will be? (3-4): ");
            wide = in.nextInt();
        }while (wide < MINWINDE || wide > MAXWIDE);

        do {
            System.out.print("How tall each window will be? (3-4): ");
            tall = in.nextInt();
        }while (tall < MINTALL || tall > MAXTALL);

        for (; stories == 1; stories++){
            System.out.println("***********\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (; stories == 2; stories++){
            System.out.println("***********\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (; stories == 3; stories++){
            System.out.println("***********\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (; stories == 4; stories++){
            System.out.println("***********\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********         \n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n*         *\n***********");
            System.exit(0);     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. You're on the right track. Now try to write those `for` loops, show us what you tried, and we can help you improve it or fix problems.

Comment: Fixed. But I do not know if this is how to do it tho.. How do I make windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the current loops, the `System.out.println` statements and these `System.exit` statements are not entirely correct...

You have to consider that you can not draw a single window and then draw one left or right of the first one. When you print something like

```
****
*  *
*  * 
****
```

then you could then only continue and print something like

```
****
*  *
*  * 
****  ****
      *  *
      *  * 
      ****
```

or so, which is not what you want. You also have to know how wide the entire building will be, based on the width and number of the windows, and how high each story will be, based on the height of the windows.

Maybe this pseudo(*)code gives a basic idea:

```
for (int s=0; s<stories; s++)
{
    printTopRowOfStory(totalBuildingWidth);        // ***********
    printWalls(totalBuildingWidth);                // *         *
    printWindowBorders(windows, wide);             // * *** *** *
    for (int h=0; h<tall; h++)          
    {                                              
        printInnerWindowBorders(windows, wide);    // * * * * * *
    }
    printWindowBorders(windows, wide);             // * *** *** *
    printWalls(totalBuildingWidth);                // *         *
}
printFloor(totalBuildingWidth);                    // ***********
```

(*) It is not really pseudocode. You could really implement it like this. Particularly, each of the window-related methods will contain another `for`-loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But could you explain how this works?

Comment: These methods don't actually exist, but he's showing you a general overview of what your code should do, and in what order. It should help you get going on the actual implementation.

Comment: @user3268146 I'll try to help you further, if (and only if) you show that your are actually trying to solve the task, and if you have specific questions.